# How to display customised message in device while setting device state as disabled in management console?

Tags: android, android-management-api, android-device-owner

We are using Android management API in our project to control the device. We want to display customise message in device as **This device has been locked. Contact your system admin** while setting device state as **disabled**.Even though setting disabled reason in android management API, message is not getting displayed in the device. Do we need to do any extra configuration to achieve this?
Note: While setting disabled state we only get the default message as **this device isn't active. Contact your IT admin** .